# How to parse data in small parts using SAX Parser?

Tags: php, android, saxparser, commonsware-cwac

I am making a small android application in which I am using endless list view using  https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/

The data on  the server end may contain thousand of entries  so it will be quite large to download all the values at once. Should I parse the data in parts using one link or should  I break the web services in parts and call them using a sax parser in `cacheInBackground()` after some interval of time from different links.

Comment: I want the idea that should I download the whole data and then make the parts or I get the small parts of data from different links

Comment: I think major problem is not parsing I think major problem is of downloading time of large file.

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh what should I do?

Comment: can't have edit access to server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dheeresh is trying to tell you, download times will be much longer than parsing times. Hence, worry more about the download times, and worry less about the parsing times.

> Should I parse the data in parts using one link or should I break the web services in parts and call them using a sax parser in cacheInBackground() after some interval of time from different links.

You should "break the web services in parts" to download part of your data, parse that, and load it into your adapter. When the user then scrolls to the bottom again, download and parse the next part of your data and load that into your adapter. And so on.

Comment: thanks sir, I also trying to say same thing, that's why I asked Nitin regarding if he has access to server.......

Answer (score 3):

I think major problem is not parsing I think major problem is of downloading time of large file

[image]